# Store/output a number bigger than unsigned long long can store

Tags: c++, variables

With user given number (n) for example n=5, I calculate the sum of 10000,10001,10002....99999.
Works up until n=17, then I get a negative number or eventually a zero.

So my question is how do I store a number bigger than unsigned long long lets me

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
  unsigned long long n, sum;
  cin>>n;
  unsigned long long start=pow(10, n-1);
  unsigned long long finish=pow(10, n)-1;
  sum=((finish-start+1)*(start+finish))/2;
  cout<<sum<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'll likely need a big numbers library like [GMP](https://gmplib.org/). That or wait until compilers have widespread `really long long` support.

Comment: Search for "big number library"

Comment: Side note about `pow`: It works in floating point numbers and floating point numbers are imprecise. The output of `pow(5,2)` could be a perfectly reasonable, close enough value of 24.9999999997 which will truncate to a totally wrong 24 as soon as you try to stuff the result back into an integer.

Comment: @user4581301 What should I use instead of pow for precision?

Comment: If the numbers  are integer through-and-through, use dumb old multiplication in a loop. Unless you're working with exponents of two. Use bit shifting in that case. Eg:  2 to the power of 10 -> `1 << 10`.

Comment: @user4581301 Great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you don't want bother with installing some big number library like GMP, or you do it for some site like code wars then you have basically two options:

A) create your own data type to hold bigger numbers ( in this case not really recommended, as number may be insanely huge).

B) hold it as a string/char table and write a function to process adding values.

Comment: Not really keen on installing a library, so I will try holding it as a string, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @SmallTimeCppUserr please mark answer as solution so other's will know that it is already solved :)